# closed-form on linear programming optimization

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, closed-form

I am interested in the following linear programming optimization problem.

\begin{align}
 O: \max_{E_k}\sum_{k=1}^{K} E_k P_k,\\
 {\rm{subject\; to:}} \sum_{k=1}^{K} E_k\le E,
\end{align}
where $E_k$, $P_k$, $K$, and $E$ are all real constant. Is there a general closed-form expression of $P_k, k\in 1,\dots, K$ for the solution rather than using software to solve it, especially when $K$ turn to be large?

Comment: Your max indicate that we maximize on $E_k$, but then you ask for the values of $P_k$ ?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity. I want to maximize the summation of $E_kP_k$ in terms of $E_k$, and I am trying to find the solution $E_k=f(P_k)$

Comment: I suppose the $P_k$ and $E_k$ are non-negative, otherwise we can take a very low $E_k$ for a negative $P_k$. Assuming this, I guess we get $E_k=E$ for the index $k$ for which $P_k$ is maximal.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $P_k\ge 0$ and $E_k \ge 0$, this is a special case of the [continuous knapsack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_knapsack_problem), and greedy is known to be optimal.  Explicitly, take $E_k=E$ for the $k$ that corresponds to the largest $P_k$.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you state has no optimal solutions (is unbounded) unless $P_1=P_2=\cdots=P_K\geq 0$.

Indeed, since the problem is convex and the constraint qualifications are satisfied (we have a single linear constraint) the KKT conditions are both necessary and sufficient for optimality.  In the present case they amount to the existence of the Lagrange multiplier $\lambda \geq 0$ such that $P_k = \lambda$, $\sum_{k=1}^K E_k \leq E$, and $\lambda[\sum_{k=1}^K E_k - E] = 0$.
Thus when the solution exists, you can e.g. take $E_1 = E$, $E_2=\cdots=E_K=0$ as the desired closed form, among infinitely many other possibilities when $K>1$.